# Unable to make flash blink continuously and stop when button clicked

Tags: android

I tried to make flashlight blink on pressing a button continuously until the button is pressed again. The flash is blinking continuously but I am unable to stop the blinking as the app freezes. Here is my Code:

```
public void Buts1(View view) {
    CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    long blinkDelay = 50;//delay in ms
    if(textView.getText().toString().equals("ON")){
       boolean s=false;
        while (textView.getText().toString().equals("ON")){
            if(s){
                try {
                    String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                }
                s=false;
            }else{
                try {
                    String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                }
                s=true;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't stop it when any button is clicked again because you didn't implement such in your code. From what your code, the loop should only stop when the textView's text is something different from "ON". You can however modify your code to listen to button clicks or simply change the textVew's content to "OFF" or any other value.

Comment: Actually I forgot to write but the text changes to off on button click but since the whole app freezes I cannot even press a button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're freezing the UI thread here.  Also I don't see anything that sets the textView text to "OFF".

I've slightly modified your code, which assumes textView starts with the text "OFF" and will change to "ON" when you click the button.  Clicking the button again will set the textView text to "OFF" and turn the flashing off.  This works by being on a separate thread instead of the UI thread.

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            Thread flashThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean s=false;
                    long blinkDelay = 50;//delay in ms
                    while (textView.getText().toString().equals("ON")){
                        if(s){
                            try {
                                String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                                }
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            }
                            s=false;
                        }else{
                            try {
                                String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                                }
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            }
                            s=true;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
            if(textView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")){
                textView.setText("ON");
                flashThread.start();
            }else{
                flashThread.interrupt();
                try {
                    String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                }
                textView.setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please accept the answer and maybe upvote if you feel generous! :)